# Find a place lies between source and destination google maps and places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have written an application where user can enter source and destination using Google places API auto complete and he also can enter an intermediate place . I just wanna determine whether that intermediate place come along the way of source and destination .

This code was working till last week . Not sure what is the issue .

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
               body {

                       font-family: sans-serif;
                       font-size: 14px;
               }
</style>
       <title>Pillion Search Engine</title>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places,geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var locations = new Array();
            var directionsDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            //calculates distance between two points in km's
            function calcDistance(p1, p2){
                return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
             }

            function initialize() {

                alert("Inside Initialize");
                var UserSource = document.getElementById('searchTextFieldSource');
                var UserDestination = document.getElementById('searchTextFieldDestination');
                var DbSource = document.getElementById('searchTextFieldIntermediateSource');
                var DbDestination = document.getElementById('searchTextFieldIntermediateDestination');



                var ACUserSource = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(UserSource);
                var ACUserDestination = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(UserDestination);
                var ACDbSource = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(DbSource);
                var ACDbDestination = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(DbDestination);

                google.maps.event.addListener(ACDbDestination, 'place_changed', function () {
                    var place1 = ACUserSource.getPlace();

                    document.getElementById('city1').value = place1.name;

                    var place1Lat = place1.geometry.location.lat();
                    var place1Lng = place1.geometry.location.lng();

                    document.getElementById('cityLat1').value = place1Lat;
                    document.getElementById('cityLng1').value = place1Lng;

                    var obj = new Object();
                    obj.city = place1.name;
                    obj.latitude = place1.geometry.location.lat();
                    obj.longitude = place1.geometry.location.lng();
                    locations.push(obj);


                    var place2 = ACUserDestination.getPlace();
                    document.getElementById('city2').value = place2.name;
                    var place2Lat = place2.geometry.location.lat();
                    var place2Lng = place2.geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById('cityLat2').value = place2Lat;
                    document.getElementById('cityLng2').value = place2Lng;

                    var obj = new Object();
                    obj.city = place2.name;
                    obj.latitude = place2.geometry.location.lat();
                    obj.longitude = place2.geometry.location.lng();
                    locations.push(obj);

                    //For intermediate point Source
                    var place3 = ACDbSource.getPlace();
                    document.getElementById('city3').value = place3.name;
                    var place3Lat = place3.geometry.location.lat();
                    var place3Lng = place3.geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById('cityLat3').value = place3Lat;
                    document.getElementById('cityLng3').value = place3Lng;

                     //For intermediate point Destination
                    var place4 = ACDbDestination.getPlace();
                    document.getElementById('city4').value = place4.name;
                    var place4Lat = place4.geometry.location.lat();
                    var place4Lng = place4.geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById('cityLat4').value = place4Lat;
                    document.getElementById('cityLng4').value = place4Lng;

                    var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(place1Lat, place1Lng);
                    var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(place2Lat, place2Lng);



                    //alert(calcDistance(p1, p2));

                    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                    var startPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(place1Lat, place1Lng);

                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 7,
                        center: startPlace
                    }

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                    var start = $("#city1").val();
                    var end = $("#city2").val();

                    var request = {
                        origin: start,
                        destination: end,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

                    var positionsource = new google.maps.LatLng(place3Lat, place3Lng);
                    var positiondestination = new google.maps.LatLng(place4Lat, place4Lng);

                    /*if(calcDistance(positiondestination, p1)> calcDistance(positiondestination, p2)) {
                        alert("Straight path");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Reverse path");
                    }*/

                    /*var heading1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(p1, p2);
                    alert("heading1: " + heading1);

                    alert("heading2: " + heading2);*/

                    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

                            if ((google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(positionsource,
                                new google.maps.Polyline({ path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(result.routes[0].overview_polyline.points) }),
                                0.0100000000))&(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(positiondestination,
                                new google.maps.Polyline({ path: google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(result.routes[0].overview_polyline.points) }),
                                0.0100000000))) 

                            {

                                alert("Belongs to the path");
                                var heading2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(positionsource, positiondestination);
                                if(heading2<0) {
                                    alert("Reverse direction");
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Doesnt Belong to the path");
                            }

                          }
                    });
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            function refreshMap(locations) {
                google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0].latitude, locations[0].longitude),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var marker, i;

                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude),
                        map: map
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent(locations[i].city);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }


            }
        </script>
        <body>
           <div>
                   <b>Source A:</b><input id="searchTextFieldSource" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter the source" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
                    <input type="text" id="city1" name="city1" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLat1" name="cityLat1" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLng1" name="cityLng1" />  
           </div>

            <div>
                   <b>Destination B:</b><input id="searchTextFieldDestination" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter the destination" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
                    <input type="text" id="city2" name="city2" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLat2" name="cityLat2" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLng2" name="cityLng2" />  
           </div>

            <div>
                   <b>Intermediate Source C:</b><input id="searchTextFieldIntermediateSource" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter the destination" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
                    <input type="text" id="city3" name="city3" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLat3" name="cityLat3" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLng3" name="cityLng3" />  
           </div>

           <div>
                   <b>Intermediate Destination D:</b><input id="searchTextFieldIntermediateDestination" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter the destination" autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  
                    <input type="text" id="city4" name="city4" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLat4" name="cityLat4" />
                    <input type="text" id="cityLng4" name="cityLng4" />  
           </div>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="initialize();" />
            <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 600px;"></div>


       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use RouteBoxer to determine a reasonable bounds for your route.  If the intermediate point is contained by those bounds, that might be good enough, otherwise you can perform further tests (like distance from the route polyline.

Comment: That's very helpful thank you . But i only want to determine whether it falls in the route , not places near to that route .

Comment: Then as I indicated, perform further tests (like distance from the route polyline), if the distance from the route polyline is zero, it is on the route, if it is non-zero it is off the route (but you may want to play with the definition of "on the route", buildings are typically not "on the route" if they have ROOFTOP geocodes.

Comment: If it was working until last week, I would suggest you try the [release version (v=3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) rather than the experimental version.

Comment: @geocodezip how do we determine reasonable bounds for the route? (I mean the allowed range)

I started with a simple example having very short route and the bounds along that route are ((33.219103567881652, -95.93213433287627), 
(33.25507643211838, -95.89987783356179),
(33.22809678394081, -95.89987783356179),
(33.25507643211838, -95.88912566712366))

And my intermediate point is (33.237698, -95.90820100000002)

Please suggest some way to determine this.

Comment: @DeepeshShetty you did aczatly what i want , but trouble is that i have many existing routes . and when any customer add new route from source to destination i want to check if there any route which match this route. and i also need to cover cities. e.g. if there is any existing route from delhi to mumbai. and any customer enter ahmedabad to surat route. than it should match the Delhi to Mumbai route..