# javascript syntax to set object property value from external variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I can better explain my case by code snippet

```js
var cascadiaFault = new google.maps.Polyline({
    paths: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(49.95, -128.1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(46.26, -126.3),
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.3, -125.4)
    ]
});
```

the value of `paths` property should be assigned from external variable `pathsTemp`

```js
var pathsTemp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
 var bounds = boxes[i];
 // Perform search over this bounds
 pathsTemp.push(bounds.getCenter());
}
var cascadiaFault = new google.maps.Polyline({
 paths: pathsTemp;
});
```

Its not working..

Other options that I tried

`paths = pathsTemp;`  -- Not working
`paths: paths.push(pathsTmep)`   -- No syntactic error but, uncaught reference error at runtime when this line is reached

PS: I don't have javascript background and unfortunately I don't have time to start reading the syntax and rules from scratch (However, I can understand most of the js code already written)

Comment: Your second approach looks fine, are you sure `pathsTemp` is the correct array? (what does getCenter return? a new LatLng object?)

Comment: `boxes[i]` is of type `google.maps.LatLngBounds`.. `bounds.getCenter()` returns object of type `google.maps.LatLng`

Comment: @doldt you are right

Comment: a [google.maps.PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) doesn't have a `paths` property.  It only has a `path` (`paths` is for Polygons)

Comment: @geocodezip the sample presented here uses `paths` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge

Comment: Look closer. There are two samples on that page, [one for `containsLocation`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) that uses `paths` for a `google.maps.Polygon` and [one for `isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) that uses `path` for a `google.maps.Polyline`

Comment: @geocodezip, sir please refer to screen shot attached in one of my answers below. Its using paths with Polyline

Comment: OK. I stand corrected. That example is wrong (you will note that there isn't a live version of that one...)

Comment: [Issue 8270: Bug: example in documentation doesn't work](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8270)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got what the problem is

1. The correct syntax is `paths: pathsTemp`

```js
var pathsTemp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  var bounds = boxes[i];
   // Perform search over this bounds
    pathsTemp.push(bounds.getCenter());
}
var cascadiaFault = new google.maps.Polyline({
    paths: pathsTemp
});
```

2. The above code is syntactically correct, but the problem is it should be `path` instead of `paths`

Though the sample example presented at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge

uses `paths`, it works with `path` for me. May be a typo in API documentation

As expected, [documentation bug logged](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8270)

with reference to this stackoverflow discussion

Answer (score 0):

**for the person who down voted the question :** please take a look at this misleading example snippet from google documentation and change your opinion if it makes sense to you (Reputation matters a lot here, for a beginner like me)

[image]

Comment: OK. I stand corrected. That example is wrong (you will note that there isn't a live version of that one...)

Comment: @geocodezip Yeah thats what. I have looked carefully before posting, coz I don't want to lose reputation unnecessarily.

Comment: [Working version of that example](http://jsfiddle.net/f1wqyh69/) with `path` and a google.maps.Polyline.  [Broken example[(http://jsfiddle.net/f1wqyh69/1/) with `paths` (no polyline appears and no `alert`)

Comment: @geocodezip, I got that yesterday, thanks!!!  If you have some time, can you please take a look at [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476917/find-a-place-lies-between-source-and-destination-google-maps-and-places-api#comment50328714_20476917) and suggest something. Not sure you got notified

Comment: Merge this into your other answer. No need for two posts.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so shall I delete this post. It has the comments and those get deleted as well

Comment: You should. If you think any of these comments are valuable and should be part of your answer, extract them into it.