# Obtaining the Subject of a String in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I tell my Java program to find the subject of the sentence:

`I enjoy spending time with my family.`

My program should output:

`Tell me more about your family.`

How would it go about doing this?

**EDIT**

I could do this by having an array of `String` and have that filled with every noun in the English dictionary, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: What problems are you having implementing this yourself? You have to at least specify what exactly you don't understand about the problem you are trying to trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

This is way too open-ended a question. But a good place to start would be to learn about [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) concepts and then look at using a framework like [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml). It breaks down sentences into a parse tree and you can use this to identify parts of speech and things like the subject of a sentence. This is probably your best bet if you want a  reasonably-reliable method.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. It was probably the OP not liking the answer provided, albiet being a reasonable one.

Comment: @VivinPaliath looks like it has become a habit of people to down vote. It discourages beginners and destroys their reputation. I feel like StackOverflow needs to bring in some strict rules against down voting. Same thing happened with me yesterday, despite proving the idea behind my post being correct and a bug was logged at google's end [this was the question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156657/javascript-syntax-to-set-object-property-value-from-external-variable)

Comment: It is a little annoying. I think this has been brought up before, but I don't remember the arguments against it: I would rather that people be required to comment if they downvote an answer. If I get downvoted because I said something wrong or incorrect, I want to know so that I can learn. It also discourages drive-by-downvoting, which I've seen happen many times because people don't take the time to understand the context of the question itself and how the answer applies to that.